# How to load a 4 GB JSON file into Cassandra?

Tags: json, cassandra

I'm trying to load this dataset from the Yelp competition on Kaggle into Cassandra to conduct some basic queries.

Here's the link for the dataset: (https://www.kaggle.com/yelp-dataset/yelp-dataset#yelp_academic_dataset_review.json)

I saw that the COPY command usually works for CSV files, but for JSON I have to manually create a table and then load all the values onto it.

The problem is that I cannot see the values in the dataset, so even though I know the attributes, I'm unable to input the instances. Is there any tool that I can use to go about this problem in a better way?

Comment: have you try this https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/graph/dgl/dglJSON.html

Comment: Im pretty sure Spark can load Jsons directly to cassandra with the connector. Might wanna look into it.